# Unity - WASD Movement in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

Hello again my friends.

I am trying to make a 3D game in Unity in which I am trying to move my character with simple WASD keys.

However, it is successful only from one direction.  From the opposite direction the controls seem reversed.  Even when I look around with the mouse.  The game is considered to be a First-Person Shooter(FPS).

The Player code is:

```
[SerializeField]
private NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal1"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical1"));
    Vector3 velocity = direction * speed;
    velocity.y -= gravity;
    velocity = transform.TransformDirection(velocity);
    controller.Move(direction * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position = navMeshAgent.nextPosition;
}
```

What should I do?  I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your can always use this as well         `float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");`
  `Vector3 forward = transform.forward * v * speed * Time.deltaTime;`
  `Vector3 right = transform.right * h * speed * Time.deltaTime; `
  `cc.Move(forward + right);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this example to move your character use your own logic ofc and change what have to be changed

```
private float speed = 2.0f;
public GameObject character;

void Update () {
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(d)){
        transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(a)){
        transform.position += Vector3.left* speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(w)){
        transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(s)){
        transform.position += Vector3.back* speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```